# How to update Excel Sheet automatically in connection to Color List condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have made an Excel sheet, where coloring on sheet 1 is conditioned based on C="Yes/No" and D = "Yes/No", meaning if C & D = Yes, color in B is Red and if C = No and D = Yes så B = Yellow. I need an automatic function where when options in C & D are selected and the color is changed in B, så the colored B must be positioned according to the coloring order: Red as high priority at the top, then Yellow, Orange, and green accordingly. Please find  the JPEG below.
[ExcelScreenDump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPe9X.jpg)
Thanks in advance, it is much appreciated.
BR
David

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the SORT tab does not update the list automatically. However, sorting with formula does update the list automatically, but cannot be so done using color.

You would have to sort a copy of list based on the Yes and No conditions, then apply the conditional formatting the sorted table based on a sorted copy of the Yes and No conditions.